# Alarm pending intent getting called again and again

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms, android-broadcastreceiver

I have added alarms in a project I am currently working on. They are working fine with all my conditions. Facing one small problem. I have added a one-shot alarm, I want it to fire on time, which is working fine and upon reaching its time it is opening an activity with values I am sending through intent. Problem is even after the alarm has been fired, the pending intent is called up again and which opens the activity with null values when I close that activity it again pops up as many times as I close it. The pending intent is not getting cancelled after it has fired at its designated time. Below is my code to set alarm.

```
public void setAlarm(int hours, int minutes,String AMPM, String alarmType,String message, String extraMessage)
    {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int  n = rand.nextInt(10000) + 1;
        Log.e("HMA",hours+"   "+minutes+"   "+AMPM + " " + message + extraMessage);

//                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm On",
        //   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        // set selected time from timepicker to calendar
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minutes);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);


        if(AMPM.equals("PM")) {
            Log.e("PM","");
            calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
        }
        else
        {
            calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        }
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,
                MyReceiver.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager;
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        myIntent.putExtra("alarmType",alarmType);
        myIntent.putExtra("gifMessage",message);
        myIntent.putExtra("extraMessage",extraMessage);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent;

        // A PendingIntent specifies an action to take in the
        // future
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, n, myIntent, 0);

        // set alarm time
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<19) {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
        else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=19 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<=22)
        {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
        else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23)
        {
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: post your error message and also full code of this class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using IntentService instead of Service and returning START_NOT_STICKY in onStartCommand.